# How to interpret the PS1 variable in BASH?

Tags: bash

I have a bash command prompt like this:

```
someone@some-host:~$
```

I checked the `PS1`:

```
echo $PS1
```

It shows this:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

How to interpret it?  Why is it so complex?

I thought `"\u@\h:\w$"` should be enough. And I tried to set PS1 to it. It works the same or at least looks so.

Comment: Consider [unix.se] for questions more about interactive use and configuration than software development.

Comment: Please post the output of `printf "%q\n" "$PS1"`

Comment: (that said, some of this is obvious -- f/e, if you're in a chroot, this puts it in the prompt; and the sequence at the very beginning, I'd guess, resets any active color codes left over from prior commands -- though one would need to go look up an ANSI terminal sequence reference to be sure)

Comment: (and yes, as KamilCuk says, `echo $PS1` is pretty wildly unreliable -- see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` prints something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else), and [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113) over at [unix.se])

Comment: To learn about the syntax used by `PS1` See: [`man bash` section `PROMPTING`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#PROMPTING)

Comment: And `\[...]` is used around escape sequences to prevent them from counting against the column count.

Comment: ...in large part, btw, this reads as a "please explain this code" question, and those are pretty categorically closed as "too broad".

Comment: [Prompt Magic](https://www.funtoo.org/Prompt_Magic) is a good (non-official) prompt reference. See "PROMPTING" in [man 1 bash](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) for an official reference.

Comment: _I thought "\u@\h:\w$" should be enough._ : If it is good enough for you, why don't you set PS1 in that way? You are in the driver's seat, and you decide how your prompt should look like.

Comment: @user1934428 I am not a bash expert. I have tried that though a bit worried about the side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to interpret it?

`\[ ... \]` is interpreted by Bash as not visible. It matters if you want for example Home key to jump to the beginning of the line but right after prompt. Bash has to know, how many characters to jump to place the cursor right after the prompt, so it has to know how many characters were printed when printing the prompt.
https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt

`\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a` sets the title of your terminal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#OSC_(Operating_System_Command)_sequences

`${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}` Expands to the string `(<value of debian_chroot>)` when variable `debian_chroot` is set, otherwise expands to nothing. Basically it adds `(` `)` to the value of `debian_chroot`, when it is set to display it nicely. https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: Thanks. I just downloaded the Bash reference manual and will go through it.

Comment: `I just downloaded` the pdf version are not great, they do not have links. I enjoy online html versions.